# Go back to 32-bit Java in OS X so I can use Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, java-applet

Recently Apple released a Java update. I mindlessly downloaded and installed it, thinking it must be good (I know that was stupid on my part). Now chrome doesn't work where sites require Java support. In terminal, `java -version` shows I have the 64bit version installed.

I know Chrome does not support 64bit Java. I'd like to go back to the last version that worked for me, the 32-bit version.  I don't want to use Safari or Firefox. I'd like Chrome to work. I have too much invested in customizing it to work with another browser.

Comment: Peculiarly, I've found that the best way to fix Java problems is to look around on various Minecraft websites.

Comment: Have you tried going to java.com?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue with Chrome. Check the answers towards the end of this Apple Support thread for the fix: https://discussions.apple.com/message/20185736?ac_cid=tw123456#20185736

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the appropriate 32bit version of JRE from their website but first uninstall this version of java from whatever is mac's equivalent of control panel